# Getting first parameter at location in List<> android java

Tags: java, android

```
final List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Data("Batman vs Superman", "Following the destruction of Metropolis, Batman embarks on a personal vendetta against Superman ", R.mipmap.ic_apps));
        data.add(new Data("X-Men: Apocalypse", "X-Men: Apocalypse is an upcoming American superhero film based on the X-Men characters that appear in Marvel Comics ",R.mipmap.ic_apps));
        data.add(new Data("Captain America: Civil War", "A feud between Captain America and Iron Man leaves the Avengers in turmoil.  ", R.mipmap.ic_apps));
        data.add(new Data("Kung Fu Panda 3", "After reuniting with his long-lost father, Po  must train a village of pandas", R.mipmap.ic_apps));
        data.add(new Data("Warcraft", "Fleeing their dying home to colonize another, fearsome orc warriors invade the peaceful realm of Azeroth. ", R.mipmap.ic_apps));
        data.add(new Data("Alice in Wonderland", "Alice in Wonderland: Through the Looking Glass ", R.mipmap.ic_apps));
```

that is above code and the Data class is

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data>{
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public int imageId;

    Data(String title, String description, int imageId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}
```

now i only know position  for List data,
how can i get only title for example :- "Batman vs Superman" at position ?

Comment: `data.get(position).title;`. Please buy a good book about java a read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.get(pos).title` will do the job for you.

And I would suggest you to clear your basics or atleast google your problem before posting it here.